# Download file from different origin using POST request

Tags: jquery, cross-domain

I'm trying to prompt a download request from a service different than my UI service (different domain).
I was trying using something like

```
$.post(url, {param1: 'param1val', param2: 'param2val'})
```

The *server returns CSV with file headers* but **I receive the response as CSV text** and not sure how (if I can) to make it being saved as file.

Clarification which might help:
My response from server is

```
Future(Ok.chunked(rowEnumerator.andThen(Enumerator.eof))
  .withHeaders(("Content-Description", "File Transfer"), ("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "binary"), ("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","*"))
  .as("text/csv").withHeaders(CONTENT_DISPOSITION -> s"attachment; filename=resp.csv", CONTENT_TYPE->"application/x-download"))
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the problem is $.post is using AJAX and it looks like it is impossible to download a file this way.
The solution  was to dynamically creating a form element on the document body with attributes that correspond to the the data I was attempting to send in $.post.

```
var form = document.createElement("form");
form.setAttribute(...); // method, action  

// for each data element for POST request
var field = document.createElement("input");
field.setAttribute(...); // type(hidden), key, value
form.appendChild(field);  

document.body.appendChild(form)
form.submit()
```